# How to write conditional query in redshift for DCL(Data control Language) statements?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have to write some DCL(Data control Language) script for security update on the redshift databases but some statement need to run if it is running on specific database. For example:

```
create group admin;

IF database ='customer1' then
   create group customer1_admin;
   grant all on schema public to group customer1_admin;
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported in Amazon Redshift.

The closest would be a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html) where you can use `IF` logic.